# Development environment is not showing full errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment

The development environment is not showing full errors on web browser, as if you were in a production environment. This is my configuration:

```
 Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = false

  config.eager_load = false

  config.consider_all_requests_local = true

  if Rails.root.join('tmp/caching-dev.txt').exist?
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

    config.cache_store = :memory_store
    config.public_file_server.headers = {
      'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=#{2.days.seconds.to_i}"
    }
  else
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

    config.cache_store = :null_store
  end

  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  config.assets.debug = true

  config.assets.quiet = true

  config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker
end
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = true
```

In your development.rb and make sure the environment is development.

Comment: The environment is development and this variable has been setted on true.

Answer (score 0):

The following line should be set to true if you want delivery errors.

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```